# Power BI calculated table not filtering by a data slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have created a table based on a group by and after placing a data slicer into the report the columns do not update at all. The data is connected via a separate table where a controller is assigned a truck, that truck has data in a turnaround dataset and the two matrices you see are calculated off a group by on that turnaround table. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Paste your measure here, hard to see what is the problem

Comment: Yard_kpi = CALCULATETABLE(GROUPBY(Turnaround_Area_Controller, Turnaround_Area_Controller[gdgControllers_CONTROLLER], "Average Hours", AVERAGEX(CURRENTGROUP(), Turnaround_Area_Controller[Average hours])), Turnaround_Area_Controller[gdgTurnaroundExport2021_AREA] IN {"GDG JHB Depot (Entire Area)"}, Turnaround_Area_Controller[gdgControllers_CONTROLLER]<>BLANK())

Comment: The above is a similar type of calculation, the calculation in the image has been changed

Answer (score 0):

I have this original to test based on your scenario:

[image]

After import the data I test the Dax Groupby function by remove table name at the front

```
new table = GROUPBY('Group',[ITEM],"Average Volumn",
                AVERAGEX(CURRENTGROUP(),'Group'[VOLUME]))
```

As my new table do correctly return the table using Groupby

[image]

However, the table value seem to be static by not able to filter the value

[image]

In fact, there is a very simple way to achieve the filter table with average value by using original data and change the calculation method to average in the visual directly, and you can see the table result is same as groupby

[image]

When a filter the slicer, and the table change also, hope is it helping :)

[image]